# Playframework: Helpers to generate HTML5 input (type="email" or type="url")?

Tags: playframework-2.0

In Play 2.0 templates, there are some helpers to build form inputs: `@inputText`, `@inputPassword`, etc.

With existing helpers, I did not find a way to build HTML5 input like these:

```
<input type="email" ... />
<input type="url" ... />
```

Do I need to make my own helpers, or did I miss something?

Comment: This Play 2 plugin should do exactly what you want : https://github.com/loicdescotte/Play2-HTML5Tags

Comment: Why is my answer converted as a comment? I thinks it replies to the question "Do I need to make my own helpers?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play 2.0 view helper are defined in package `views.helper`. HTML 5 new types are currently missing from the [list](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.package). But it should be really easy to extend it yourself. See for example the [`@inputPassword` source](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputPassword.scala.html).

Answer (score 4):

Seems [some one](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/1cb00d5144feb37b934d15d76c59ce442b95879c) already fixed this in 2.0.4. You can now do this:

```
@inputText(
  myform("email"),
  '_showConstraints -> false,
  '_label -> Messages("label.email"),
  'type -> "email"
)
```